# Beginner CSS Trouble - Margin Appears in IE But Not Chrome or FireFox

Tags: html, css, web

I know it has to be my own fault, but I'm not seeing what I've done wrong.  Looks exactly as expected in Chrome and FireFox.  Fails in IE9.  I used the W3C CSS validator and it came back clean.

All I want is some text (horizontally aligned to the left, vertically aligned to the bottom) and an image (a banner add) on the same line.

```
<div id="header">
    <span id="logo">MyCoolLogoText!</span>
    <img id="ad1" src="banner.jpg">     
</div>
```

My CSS has gotten longer as I've struggled with this but it is currently

```
#logo {
width:507px;
height:65px;
display:inline; 
float:left;
text-align:left;    
vertical-align: text-bottom;
color:white;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:rgb(77,00,00);
}

#ad1 {
float:left;
display:inline;
width:468px;
height:65px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#header 
{   
    width:975px;    
    height:75px;    
    margin:0;   
    padding:0;    
}
```

Internet Explorer would place the Span on the first line and then the Image on the next line.  If I reduced the width of either they would both appear on the top line.  I'm assuming IE is adding a margin or padding of some sort; but I've tried to tell it not to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I've added the styling info for #header

Comment: What are the styles on #header? It sounds like padding in the container causing the wrapping. Also, display:inline and a float is a sort of contradiction (float taking precedence); float makes it a block element, which is the only reason you're able to change the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be adding `margin` or `padding`, so make sure you have:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

However, it could just be your window width. Since you are floating the objects, and they have fixed widths, then you can get the same effect you are seeing in IE9 on any browser by simply shrinking the browser window width. That is the nature of how float's work. To fix that, do this (based off what I see with your current margin, padding, and border settings):

```
#header {
    min-width: 975px; /* the width of your two floated elements */
}
```

You could use `width` instead of `min-width`.

EDIT: Okay, you had the width on the header. I did notice that your syntax on the `img` tag is not correct. You have `<img id="ad1" src="banner.jpg">` but it is missing the closing slash `<img id="ad1" src="banner.jpg" />`. I doubt that is the problem, but on the other hand, browsers can do funny things with invalid code.

Comment: Whether the _<img>_ needs to be self-closing depends on the doctype. In XHTML you're correct, in plain HTML _<img>_ is a void element and does not need a closing slash.

Comment: Good point. I am so used to coding for XHTML that I forgot about earlier standards.

Answer (score 1):

Try displaying #ad1 as inline-block and floating it to the right. Also whack an overflow of hidden onto the #header if you want it to enclose the foats (provided you don't need anything to overflow it).